# How to fetch data from access database in a textBox using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I have a database in which I created a table `HUGO_BOSS`. Its columns are `[brand name]`, `[stock quantity]`, `[retail price]` and its primery key is `[Brand name]`. I want to fill my textbox in windows form with the value of stock quantity present in my database. I tried the following code but it gives run-time error

> The Connection was not close, the connection state is open.

```
if (comboBox2.Text == "HUGO BOSS")
{
    try
    {
        OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "Select [Stock quantity] as stockquantity from HUGO_BOSS WHERE [Brand name]=@name";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", comboBox3.SelectedItem);
        con.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox7.Text = dr["stockquantity"].ToString();
        }
    }
    finally { con.Close(); }
}
```

One more thing, here I will select the primary key by using a `combobox3`

Answer (score 1):

It looks you're trying to reuse a database connection that is already open.

You could try testing the connection state before trying to open it:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select [Stock quantity] as stockquantity from HUGO_BOSS WHERE [Brand name]=@name";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", comboBox3.SelectedItem);
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    con.Open();
}
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult);
if (dr.Read())
{
    textBox7.Text = dr["stockquantity"].ToString();
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a new connection each time you need to execute a new command.

Comment: it gives an error "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."

Comment: @Dany In your question you say the table name is `HUGGO_BOSS`, but in the SQL code you're querying table `HUGO_BOSS` (only one `G`). Are you sure the SQL query is correct? Also, what type is `comboBox3.SelectedItem`?

Comment: sorry, actually there is a typing mistake in question.The correct spelling is HUGO_BOSS and my combobox3 contains the list of brand name from the database. If a users selects a particular brand name, then my textbox should give its quantity available in the stock.

Comment: @Dany If `SelectedItem` is a string, are you sure that `[Brand Name]` in a `varchar` or `nvarchar` (or `char` / `nchar`)? Also, did you specify the database name in your connection string?

Comment: yes i specified the database name in connection string. and my brand name is a text. Actually i am using ms access database.

Comment: @Dany It looks like this error can be generated by wide range of issues, so it's hard to tell what's causing it without knowing more about your code. Do a Google search for this error message to see what kinds of issues might exist in your project.